# Will restoring wp-config.php delete/reset current WP database

Tags: wordpress

THe wp-config.php file in our WordPress suddenly went missing. We did not do any reinstallation or uninstallation.

We searched the backup folder and found a copy of that file. I am not sure what will happen to our WP database if I simply copypaste the original file from our backup.

The recovered wp-config.php file contains the correct database name and database-related info (password, etc.).

If I restored that file, will it erase the current content of our WP database, especially wp_posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, restoring the `wp-config.php` file from your backup will not erase your site content. That file contains the information that WordPress needs to *connect* to the database, but it does not contain site content itself. Once it has been configured (when you first set up the WordPress site) the contents of the `wp-config.php` file should never change.